# UITableView expandable/collapsable sections in iOS 8,Particular row section is not expandable/collapsable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

After lots of googling for UITableView expandable/collapsable sections i still didn't get correct answer and also i have tried but still got nothing.

[image]

When i clicked the first section of reminder,it hides like this.

[image]

So here is my question to make it right. I'm working on an application where i need to expand collapse rows in different sections. Initially I tried expanding collapsing rows with a single section. Now I want the same to happen in multiple sections.Can anyone tell me what wrong i have done and suggest me.

```
 BOOL expand,collapsed;


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


//Headerview
     myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 80.0)];

// Add the label
      UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kSectionTitleLeftMargin,
kSectionTitleTopMargin,tableView.bounds.size.width - kSectionTitleLeftMargin - kSectionTitleRightMargin,30.0 - kSectionTitleTopMargin - kSectionTitleBottomMargin)];

 // do whatever headerLabel configuration you want here
headerLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
[myView addSubview:headerLabel];


UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

 //up or down arrow depending on the bool

UIImageView *upDownArrow        = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:expand ?  [UIImage imageNamed:@"upArrowBlack"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"downArrowBlack"]];
upDownArrow.autoresizingMask    = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
upDownArrow.frame               = CGRectMake(265.0, 2.5, 25.0, 25.0);
[myView addSubview:upDownArrow];

return myView;
}

#pragma mark - gesture tapped
- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];

 {
   collapsed       = !collapsed;

//   reload specific section animated

  NSRange range   = NSMakeRange(indexPath.section, 1);
  NSIndexSet *sectionToReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
   [self.tableView reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   [self.tableView reloadData];


}

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
   if (reminders.count!=0)
  {
    return 2;
}
else
{
    return 1;
}
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 30;
}


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
if ((reminders.count!=0) && (section==0))
{

    return reminders.count;
}

else
{
return 15;
}
}
```

Comment: where you are adding/deleting rows?

Comment: @johnykumar i think still you didn't get the point .UITableviewcell rows should expand when section is clicked and also for multiple section with with that particular array cell.No need for adding/deleting.

Comment: You have to delete the rows from the model (and the table). It would be easier if you refactored your design to create a Collapsible Section class to handle all the details, and forward your tableview delegate methods to those classes

Comment: for expanding there should be some rows in that section.you have array of tableview cells?

Comment: @johnykumar yes ,Check my first picture which i uploaded and after clicked the first section both arrays not showing but section should collapse.

Comment: you have to remove rows from table.it should work like toggle.

Comment: @johnykumar how should i,suggest me some codings.

Comment: send me your mail i will send you sample which i have

Comment: @johnykumar ganesh@chennainet.in

Answer (score 0):

`Here is the sample for Collapsable Tableview.`

```
method for tab gesture
-(void)sectionButtonTouchUpInside:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer{
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
UIView *sender = [gestureRecognizer view];
int section = sender.tag;
bool shouldCollapse = ![_collapsedSections containsObject:@(section)];
if (shouldCollapse) {
    NSArray* indexPaths = [self indexPathsForSection:section withNumberOfRows:[[_arrItems objectAtIndex:section] count]];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [_collapsedSections addObject:@(section)];
}
else {
    NSArray* indexPaths = [self indexPathsForSection:section withNumberOfRows:[[_arrItems objectAtIndex:section] count]];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [_collapsedSections removeObject:@(section)];
}
[self.tableView endUpdates];
}

-(NSArray*) indexPathsForSection:(int)section withNumberOfRows:(int)numberOfRows {
NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
    [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
}
return indexPaths;
}
```

Comment: How can this be possible in swift

Comment: let me convert it in swift