# Swift: CollectionViewCell Expansion

Tags: swift, user-interface, uicollectionview

I'm currently building an app that allows for me and my fellow classmates to access our grades with ease.

This is what the main interface looks like:
[image: CourseViewController]

What I'm planning on doing is to detect when the user clicks on one of the Course Cells, which will then trigger an expansion showing more details. Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve:

[image: Example]

I thought about inserting a new custom CollectionViewCell beneath the cell that was tapped on, but that didn't work out well, tossing Inconsistency Exceptions at me.

**What's the best way to do this?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to use UITableview instead of UICollectionView. I don't know why are you used UICollectionView.

Comment: @Jasmit For what reason exactly, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531242/uitableview-expandable-collapsable-sections-in-ios-8-particular-row-section-is-n and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938921/expand-collapse-section-in-uitableview-in-ios please check. Uitableview easy to manage compare to UICollectionView.

Comment: @Jasmit Not always the case. But If I were to stick to CollectionViews, what would be the ideal way to accomplish expandible cells?